# Xcode Performance

Tags: xcode, macos

I am using XCode 11.3.1 and and iMac, 2017, 3.4GHz, Quad core i5 with 16GB of memory, Catalina 10.15.2.  XCode seems very slow at times (e.g., startup, build times, preview times, simulator launch).  It is particularly a problem for preview.  Preview operations seem to take minutes at times.  Using the activity monitor, I note that CPU utilization is low (well below that of a single core), memory pressure is low, and there appears to be minimal disk activity.  The only culprit I can think of is network access.  Network access may come into play because my project is located in Documents and Documents is on my iCloud Drive.  Network access may also be an issue if XCode is extremely chatty for reasons of which I am unaware.  My network latency is estimated to be 50ms.

Even so, if I move everything off iCloud, there is no noticable change in performance.  I have also encountered file not found errors on added files that were located on iCloud drive. In this case, the files were added to the project, but not copied and the files had not been downloaded yet.

What should I be expecting for Xcode performance?

Comment: How much disk space do you have left on your laptop? How big is your project? There are several resources around clearing out old simulators and versions of Xcode that might be lying around. (This question will probably be closed or moved to another network soon as it's off topic for StackOverflow I think).

Comment: The machine was recently re-imaged; so, Xcode was just reloaded.  The project is relatively small I would think -- a dozen or so source files.  There is plenty of disk space.  I generally put all my projects in tech-stack related folders in Documents which is on my iCloud Drive.  Some non-xcode projects are web related and have 10,000s of files. Some articles suggest that spotlight indexing might be a problem.  Given the number of files I have on iCloud Drive, indexing activity, and network latency, maybe this is a problem.

Comment: Hmm... it could be that. Would it not be preferable to use a local directory and GitHub (or some other source control)? That way Xcode isn’t fighting with iCloud?